# Render Shortcode in Lightbox Gallery

Tags: plugins, gallery, videos, cdn, lightbox

I am trying to have a video gallery, but I use HolaCDN. Their wordpress plugin lets you insert videos using a shortcode, and that shortcode inserts the necessary javascript to render their video player, which is optimized to use their CDN.

I can't find any way to do the following:

- A gallery of images (I can supply image files for thumnails)
- When clicked on, a lightbox comes up
- The lightbox content is the shortcode for HolaCDN so that their video player renders within the lightbox.

There are tons of gallery and lightbox plugins, but they all seem to require a youtube link or image file from the media library. Is there any way to achieve this easily using common (preferably free) plugins?

Comment: Or you can create your own plugin, that take the data from the CDN and renders. For me is the best solution as you have more control over the functionality and won't need to tweak third party code.

Comment: That solution makes sense for large, inflexible projects, but for this project I don't want to invest the time to do that (client's userbase is relatively small, and there is a fixed number of videos). If this is the only option it would likely be quicker to just switch to a different cdn.